# CSS Zoom 1 automatically added to document

Tags: css, html, styles

I am building a simple website and for some reason "zoom : 1" is added to the body, like this:

```
"style = 'zoom:1;'"
```

Needles to say I did not added this nor does this ever appears in the php file or the css file.
Spooky.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which browser do you use? Maybe you use plugins? Can you reproduce an example? Are you using javascript?

Comment: Not enough info for us to really help you. Does it happen in all browsers or just in a specific one? Is it in the generated HTML code or is it in the DOM but not the actual HTML code (use view source to check)? This will help determine whether it's generated by Javascript or by your back-end code. You might also want to tell us a bit more about the technologies you're using to build the site; are you using a CMS platform like Drupal or Wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes browser add zoom:1 automatically, it doesn't do any thing.zoom:1 is a normal zoom and does not magnify anything in your website.

Comment: Since when have browsers ever added CSS as inline styles to the DOM automatically? Never, that's when

Comment: there is a browser styesheet,for example in chrome browser css shows in grey boxes, and I've seen this zoom:1 once in that,my point was that doesn't do any harm